# This reinitialization might get skipped error when using timeit crate in rust

Tags: rust

```rust
for i in 1..8 {
   let nums = (0..40_320).collect::<Vec<i32>>();
   let mut sum = 0;
   timeit!(
       { sum = adder(nums, i); }
   );
   assert_eq!(812_831_040, sum);
}
```

```
let nums = (0..40_320).collect::<Vec<i32>>();
    ----   --------------------------------- this reinitialization might get skipped
   |
   |     move occurs because `nums` has type `Vec<i32>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
   |    let mut sum = 0;
   | /  timeit!(
   | |     { sum = adder(nums, i); }
   | |                  ^^^^ value moved here, in previous iteration of loop
   | |  );
   | |_____________- inside of this loop
```

I was expecting the code to work like it did before adding timeit! macro.

Answer (score 2):

Code in the [`timeit!`](https://docs.rs/timeit/latest/timeit/macro.timeit.html) macro can be ran multiple times to get an average of execution time. And it appears that your `adder` function *consumes* the vector passed to it. You should either change it to accept the data by reference or you'll need to recreate/`.clone()` the vector within the timed block.